# How to get AppID on iPhone using SDK/programmatically?

Tags: iphone, http, request

I want to send the `AppID` as a HTTP URL parameter for all web-service requests, but I do not know how to get the `AppID` on iPhone programmatically.
Does Apple provide any API to obtain the `AppID`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it may be possible to access it in a different way, but you should be able to read it from your info.plist:

```
NSString* appID = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
```

Comment: This gives you the bundle id, which is separate from the iTunesConnect App ID. I don't believe it is possible to access the actual App ID programmatically, especially from a development build.

Comment: you can save the Itunes App ID to your info.plist and use the code above to obtain it at run time

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *appID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Comment: The bundle identifier is not the same thing as the app ID. bundle id looks like org.example.app and is set in Xcode in your Info.plist.  AppID is a large number assigned by Apple. You can see both for your app from App Store Connect in the App Information section.